# Stringified data sent via Jquery post is unusable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, stringify

I am stringifieng an object in javascript, and sending it via Jquery post method:

```
reservation={};
count=0;
$(".reservation").each(function() {
    reservation[this.id]=jQuery(this).val();
    count++;
    if (count==jQuery(".reservation").length)
    {
        reservationString=JSON.stringify(reservation);
        $.post("helper.php", {reservation: reservationString}) .done(function(data) {
```

The "helper.php" file gets the data, but the quotatian marks are all escaped, so when I try to decode it, I get a json error, with error code 4.

Here is the helper.php file:

```
$reservation=$_REQUEST['reservation'];
echo $reservation . "\n";
$reservation=json_decode(html_entity_decode($reservation));
```

I tried alerting out the reservationString in javascript, the string is not escaped there, so most likely the jQuery post method escapes the string for me. What could be the problem, can you guys suggest a solution?

Additional Infos:
This is what I get after alerting out the stringified object in javascript:

```
{"test":"bubub","Domain":"online","Type":"banner","s2id_CompanyId":"","CompanyId":"-","ContactPersonId":"0"}
```

This is what I get after echoing out the data in php:

```
{\"test\":\"bubub\",\"Domain\":\"online\",\"Type\":\"banner\",\"s2id_CompanyId\":\"\",\"CompanyId\":\"-\",\"ContactPersonId\":\"0\"}
```

Comment: Check if magic quotes is enabled on your server, if it is either disable it, or if you cant, use stripslashes on `$reservation`

Comment: stripslashes did the job for now, but I am also checking out magic quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$reservation=$_REQUEST['reservation'];
echo $reservation . "\n";
$reservation=stripslashes(json_decode(html_entity_decode($reservation));
```